# Gráfico de Barra para 2 variables categóricas con ggplot2

Tags: r

Quiero hacer un gráfico de barras donde el eje x tenga el código de la carrera y el y la cantidad de mujeres de esa carrera y varones de esa carreras. Donde Sexo (varón:0, mujer:1) y carrera_Codigo (códigos del 1 al 22). Mi tabla se llama data. Copié de internet el siguiente código:

```
data <- read_excel("D:/PRUEBAS en R/Ingresantes_2015_USAR_R.xlsx")
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Carrera_Codigo, y='Edad al 9/3/15',fill=Sexo))+ 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")

library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
group_by(Carrera_Codigo, Sexo) %>% 
count() -> conteos
conteos

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Carrera_Codigo, y = n, fill = Sexo)) +   
geom_col()
```

Pero me salta el siguiente mensaje de error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = n. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?

El código que copié era para dos variables numéricas pero no sé cómo adaptarlo a mis variables categóricas.
Alguien puede orientarme????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu caso particular el problema es que haces el `data.frame` con las frecuencias, al que nombras `conteos`, pero luego en la llamada a `ggplot` indicas que los datos que debe usar para el gráfico se llaman `data`. Entonces no encuentra las columnas `Carrera_código`, `Sexo` y `n`.

Sin embargo hay otro problema antes de ese problema. Tus datos originales, importados del Excel, se llaman `data`. El problema es que `data()` también es una función base de `R` y ahí es dónde `ggplot` se confunde y va a buscar columnas a un objeto que no es un data.frame, sino una función. No las encuentra y por eso interrumpe y emite el mensaje de error.

En algunos casos `R` es capaz de resolver la ambigüedad entre `data` -objeto data.frame- y `data()` -llamada a una función. Sin embargo `ggplot` usa internamente una técnica que se llama Evaluación No Estándar y ahí la distinción entre objeto y nombre de objeto es menos clara (técnicamente, se pierde la transparencia referencial). Por eso es recomendable no usar nombres para nuestros datos que coincidan con funciones de R. Quienes trabajamos en español tenemos una ventaja en ese sentido, como casi todas las funciones tienen nombres en inglés basta con usar un nombre en español para evitar estas superposiciones. Por ejemplo `datos`. Mejor aún, usar un nombre que remita directamente a lo que contienen los datos, en tu caso podría ser `estudiantes` , `ingresantes` o algo así.

Va un ejemplo reproducible del problema.

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars

data %>% 
  group_by(vs, am)

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

# Aquí ya sale el error, `group_by()` recibe del lado 
# izquierdo de la tubería una función y no tiene un método
# que aplicarle. `group_by` solo "come" data.frame

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, am) %>% 
  count() -> conteo #Estrictamente son frecuencias, la N es conocida

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = am, y = n, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_col()

Error: You re passing a function as global data.
Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`

# El error no es exactamente el mismo que recibes, pero el problema es el mismo

ggplot(data = conteo, aes(x = am, y = n, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_col()

# Este sí funciona porque llama a unos datos que están en un data.frame
# y no hay confusión con una función.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora vi mi error :).